# Sublime Text editor plug-in, scan div id's and classes

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2

I'm aware I'm supposed to show some starting code to give you a clue as to what I'm trying to do, but I'm really at a basic level and I can't find any resources to show me what I'm after. Basically, I'm trying to write a plug-in for Sublime Text editor, which selects all div ID's then outputs them into a file. What's the best approach? It seems like it should be easy, but I'm not too sure.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Ewan

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good place to start: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-basics

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html, though be advised that Sublime Text 3 is currently in beta. It introduces changes to the plugin api, and a requirement to support Python 3. See http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/porting_guide.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some familiarity with python, I would start with this tutorial on for writing plugins ([Link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin/)). The author of that tutorial wrote, among other things, package control. Granted, it is for ST2, but for what you are trying to do, I don't for see any major issues with writing a plugin that is compatible with both ST2 and ST3.

How you go about writing your particular plugin is up to you. One approach may be leveraging the view.find_all() method. This takes a regular expression and returns a set of regions. From these regions, you can grab the text, and subsequently the IDs for the divs. There may be a better way, but that might work as an initial attempt. Writing to a file can be done through the usual python means.